# Voice chat application mutes sound of all other applications when using Bluetooth headsets on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, skype, wireless-headset

I'm having the same problem as this question:
[Can't hear other programs' sound when using Bluetooth headsets with voice chat applications on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1164714/cant-hear-other-programs-sound-when-using-bluetooth-headsets-with-voice-chat-a/1373617#1373617?newreg=610523f563584dcf94346d59ff964921)

I have tried all the solutions referenced by that post.

Here's what I want: I would love to use AirPods (2019 version) to chat (through Discord) with friends while playing PC games. But getting in a Discord call mutes all other applications, and all the setting tweaks I've tried don't give me the desired solution (listening and talking into the AirPods at the same time during a call).

The above referenced post proposed Bluetooth 5.0 as a potential solution. Does anyone know if that solves it? Would the increased bandwidth prevent Windows from switching to the "hands-free profile"?

Comment: I presume you have a separate microphone for the setup you describe?  I also assume you have configured your speakers to that of the Airpods and the Microphone within Discord?

Comment: No, the goal is to use the AirPods for both audio in and audio out. Why do you assume otherwise?

Comment: I tried a Bluetooth 5 headset with an older laptop and it didn't fix the problem, but I am not sure if the computer needs to be Bluetooth 5 as well

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the speaker symbol in your task bar, there appears a pop-up with the volume slider and above that there's written something like Airpods Stereo. Click on that and select Airpods Hands Free AG from the list. Thats because windows has a seperate driver for calls via bluetooth headsets which you have to select as your system's output device.