# Bluetooth headset microphone doesn't work with stereo headphones enabled

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth, microphone

I have a Bluetooth headset ([Dali IO-4](https://www.dali-speakers.com/headphones/io-4/)) which is connected to my PC via [Gigabyte GC-WBAX200](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GC-WBAX200-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver) Wifi/Bluetooth PCI-E card. The PC is running Windows 10 Home Edition (build 19041).

I know that there has been issues where you couldn't use the headset as stereo headphones, while at the same time using the microphone, due to the lack of bandwidth, as described in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1164714/cant-hear-other-programs-sound-when-using-bluetooth-headsets-with-voice-chat-a).

However, both devices are supporting the Bluetooth 5 protocol which, to my knowledge, should provide enough bandwidth to fix this issue. Do I need to configure something?

The headset shows up as two individual devices: Stereo headphones (blue circle) and headset (red circle). Either works individually, but I cannot use the headphones as output and the headset as input.

[image: Screenshot from sound settings]

Comment: Bandwidth isn't the issue. Its the simple fact that the device only supports using one profile at a time.

Comment: Thanks @Mokubai, that's also what the other posts said. Do you have any idea if they are planning any profiles which supports stereo sound at the same time as voice?

Comment: Sadly no, I've just resigned my fate to completely disabling the hands-free profile and using a separate microphone. Bluetooth HFP microphones tend to sound like crap so using the one built into my laptop is a no-brainer while I get good sound *from* the laptop using the much better A2DP audio output.