# Is there a way to disable hands-free telephony for Bluetooth without disabling your mic on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone

If not, how do I go about fixing Bluetooth's garbage audio (hissing and popping like hold music, or not even existent, depending on what application is using my mic) whenever I am using my mic in any sort of call?

Any audio from the call itself is fine (for instance, other people in a Discord or Skype call), but audio from any other application (a game, or Spotify) is either muted or has the quality downgraded to hold music.

I have tried updating my audio drivers and drivers for my Bluetooth headphones (no change), disabling Handsfree Telephony (which disables my mic) turning my computer off and on (duh, but this is a persistent issue between restarts and apps so no change), as well as a host of other solutions.

Can this be fixed on the software end, or is it purely a hardware issue? I have heard many differing opinions on this, though after seeing someone that has been trying to fix this on the software end for literal years, I am beginning to lose hope that it can be solved without purchasing a non-Bluetooth headset.

Comment: That's how BT headsets work. You should have 2 devices - headphones (good sound quality, no mic) and headset (worse sound quality). BT can't handle both good input and output quality at the same time. This is kind of a duplicate of question below, but from the 2nd angle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't hear other programs' sound when using Bluetooth headsets with voice chat applications on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1164714/cant-hear-other-programs-sound-when-using-bluetooth-headsets-with-voice-chat-a)