# Trouble using bluetooth headset with Skype

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, skype

I have a pair of [Phasier HBS-730](https://phaiser.com/products/phaiser-bhs-730-tecton-bluetooth-headphones) Bluetooth earbuds.  I like to listen to Spotify, and I also like to use Skype.  Both of these work fine, but only independently.  Not at the same time.  Also, I am using the new Skype (the Windows 10 version)  Let me explain:

The headset has 2 channels.  One is called "Stereo" and one is "Hands-Free", as shown below.

[image: Both Playback Channels as seen in Sound Settings]

Spotify plays through the "Stereo" channel.  This is because first, it makes sense,  as Spotify is not a communications application.  Secondly, if I try to play Spotify through the "Hands-Free" channel, it has awful sound quality (like that of a very old radio).

Conversely, Skype uses the "Hands-Free" channel.  This makes sense, because it is a communications device.  And if I try to use Skype through the "Stereo" channel, I don't hear any *call* sound.  I do hear other sounds, like the little blip you hear when a call ends, and other app sounds like that.  But I don't hear anything that the other person says in the call.

In addition to these issues, problems arise when I try to listen to Spotify while on a Skype call (not just Spotify- everything I am about to say here holds true for anything, including YouTube, Spotify, Netflix, etc., basically all media sounds).  There are a few different scenarios, which I will describe below:

***Scenario 1:*
Skype Channel: Hands-Free
Spotify Channel: Stereo**
In this scenario, each program works fine alone.  However, the sound from Spotify will not work when Skype is in a call.  As soon as Skype begins using the "Hands-Free" channel, it blocks out the "Stereo" channel.  An important note is that it does NOT pause Spotify; the songs keep playing.  I just can't hear them.  As soon as I end the Skype call, the music comes back.  To make things worse, when I am in this setup and go to Skype settings and click "Test audio", I CAN hear the audio.  And it doesn't mute Spotify.  However, it is just playing a ringtone and not simulation call audio, so that is probably why it works.  *This is the setup that makes the most sense, and the one that I think is correct.*

***Scenario 2:*
Skype Channel: Hands-Free
Spotify Channel: Hands-Free**
In this scenario, I CAN hear both at the same time!  Which is great but- the Spotify audio quality is terrible.  The Skype call quality is perfect, but for some reason when playing a non-communications software audio through the "Hands-Free" channel, it doesn't sound good at all.  *This is the closest to what I want.*

***Scenario 3:*
Skype Channel: Stereo
Spotify Channel: Stereo**
In this scenario, I can hear Spotify when it is playing, but I can't hear the Skype call audio.  And on top of that, when I start a call while Spotify is playing, it still cuts out the Spotify audio, so I hear NOTHING, no Spotify and no Skype.  *This is the configuration that I would most expect to work.*

As you can probably imagine, this is very frustrating.  I have tried continuously to get this to work.  Note that this only is a problem when I am using my Bluetooth headset.  When I try to just use my computer speakers, it works perfectly fine.  I can hear Spotify and the Skype call at the same time, and they are both high-quality.  However, I am not always ok with playing my audio out loud, especially because my computer speakers are not very loud and it is hard to use Skype (even when I don't have music playing) because it is difficult to hear.  But also for privacy reasons, I need to use the headphones sometimes.  And I would rather not by wired earbuds :).

Additionally, I have attempted to disable "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device" for both the "Hands-Free" channel and the "Stereo" channels (shown below).  I went through all three of the above scenarios with both checked, then only one checked, then the other checked, then neither checked (like a science experiment) and it had no affect.

[image]

And no, I don't have Windows Sound Settings set to mute other applications during communications activity:

[image]

**Some technical specs:**

- I am using a [Dell XPS 15
  9560](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/xps-15/spd/xps-15-9560-laptop), non-touch
- Running Windows 10 Pro
- Skype 11.19.856.0
- Spotify 1.0.62.510.g918a790c

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask me and I will do my best to answer them.  I really want to figure this out, I just can't comprehend or accept the idea that it isn't possible.  I mean it worked with the classic version of Skype (if I remember correctly), but I prefer the new Skype.  And I think they are going to deprecate the classic version soon.

I appreciate any help that I could get on resolving this issue!  Thanks!

Comment: This question is answered here: [https://superuser.com/a/925585/235005](https://superuser.com/a/925585/235005)